# Is this true or false, and what is the explanation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus

If A is a square matrix, does det(-A) = -det(A)?

Comment: $\det kA=k^n\det A$ where $A$ is $n\times n$ and $k$ is a scalar.

Comment: Does it work for the identity matrix?

Comment: $\det\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=1$ while $\det -\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=1$ so it's not really true. The matrix has to be of odd dimension for this to be true, otherwise $\det(-A)=\det(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the sign of a row or column
changes the sign of the determinant.

Changing the sign of $n$ rows
or columns multiplies the determinant
by $(-1)^n$.

Therefore ...

Comment: so the answer depends on n and not the fact that it is a square matrix?

Comment: Both, since the determinant is usually not defined for a non-square matrix.

Answer (score 0):

As $$|kA|=k^n|A|$$ so If $A$ is a square matrix of odd order then $$|-A|=-|A|$$ but in case of even order $$|-A|=|A|$$